# how to detect computer vision blob of pixels within specific color range, using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-detection, matlab-cvst

What Matlab computer vision functions will detect, in a single video frame, a blob that is (mostly) of pixels all within a specific color range?

I want to detect stationary objects, and am looking for a non-movement function that can detect blobs for each frame.

For example, if I want to detect any red object, like an apple of a specific color, sitting on a table.

I'm trying the Vision.blobAnalysis() but I'm not sure if it only works with moving blobs.  The Matlab Help is not clear on this.

Comment: if you are looking for something red (specific color does not matter), why not just use the R layer of the image, find all pixels that have a value between some range, and then use that resulting logical image to get the image properties you want.

Comment: How do I get the color from step() in imaq.VideoDevice?  I can't find description of format of step() output.  Actually will be using thermal infrared camera, and want to filter for specific temperature range.